# Irrational Number modulo Prime

Tags: number-theory, exponentiation, irrational-numbers

Given three positive integers $a$,$r$ and $n$, I need to calculate $\left\lfloor(a+\sqrt{r})^n\right\rfloor$ mod $p$, where $p$ is a prime.

Let $\left\lfloor(a+\sqrt{r})^n\right\rfloor=c+d\sqrt{r}$.

We can use binary exponentiation method to calculate $c$ mod $p$ and $d$ mod $p$. That doesn't help to calculate its floor modulo prime. Is there a fast method to do this without actually evaluate the whole thing? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: That looks very strange. Why do you want to do it?

Comment: This is a part of a problem from a programming competition. I read about Beatty sequence, but that didn't help much. Taking convergents of $\sqrt{r}$ wasn't useful either.

Comment: If $\left|a-\sqrt{r}\right|<1$, then you may use a recurrence for $(a+\sqrt{r})^n+(a-\sqrt{r})^n$ (again with the idea of binary exponentiation). BTW, could you give a link to the original problem?

Comment: https://projecteuler.net/problem=721 $|a-\sqrt{r}|<1$ is true in this case. Could you please elaborate what you mean by that recurrence?

Comment: I see, that is identical to original, only that we exclude the irrational parts. Very clever idea :)